# Cosmos DB overwrite existing documents

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-cosmosdb

Currently, I have this, which works fine.

```
this.container.items
  .create<Session>(data)
  .then(() => callback(null))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("error >>>", error)
    callback(error)
  });
```

However, if I try to create another document with the same ID, I get the error:

> message: 'Entity with the specified id already exists in the system.

Is it possible to make Cosmos ignore it and overwrite the document, or is there a method on the NodeJS SDK for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use [Upsert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/items?view=azure-node-latest#upsert-t--requestoptions-) if you want to upadate the entire document , if you need to change few fields then consider using [Patch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/item?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-cosmos-item-patch) operation

**Upsert**

```
  const { resource: upsertedPerson1 } = await container.items.upsert(upsertSource);
```

**Patch**

```
 const { resource: patchSource1 } = await container.item(patchId!).patch(replaceOperation);
```

Check the samples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/cosmosdb/cosmos/samples/v3/typescript/src/ItemManagement.ts).

Answer (score 0):

You can use UPSERT method of items.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/items?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-cosmos-items-upsert-1

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. This type of link could be a comment under the question, but not an answer (the OP still has to go somewhere else, following your link, to figure out how upserts work, and how they may or may not solve their problem)